# Remove Field From Collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How can I remove a field from a collection?

I found the method `removeFieldFromSelect()` in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`, but it does not seems to work.

I tried:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('bannermanagement/banner')->getCollection();
$collection->removeFieldFromSelect('status');
```

but still the field shows up. How can I remove the field Status from collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked that `removeFieldFromSelect` is available in Magento, but it not used anywhere. However, you can achieve it like this:

Clone your Collection in your custom module Collection file

`$idsSelect = clone $this->getSelect();`

and then reset the Columns

`$idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);`

and then set the columns again

`$idsSelect->columns($this->getResource()->getIdFieldName(), 'main_table');`